# Como eliminar o espaço deixado por views invisíveis na tela?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação android e minha dúvida é: Quando o usuário loga no aplicativo, ele verifica as permissões do mesmo.
Como posso fazer esse botão ficar invisível e organizar para não ficar em branco o espaço que esse botão ocupava ?

Abaixo alguns botões que estou utilizando na classe do Menu:

```
  btnDadosCadastrais      = (Botton) findViewById(R.id.dadosCadastrais);
        btnDadosCadastrais.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnDebitosPendentes     = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.debitosPendentes);
        btnDebitosPendentes.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnHistoricoPagementos  = (Botton) findViewById(R.id.HistoricoPagamento);
        btnHistoricoPagementos.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnSolicitarAtendimento = (Botton) findViewById(R.id.solicitarAtendimento);
        btnSolicitarAtendimento.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnHistoricoAtendimento = (Botton) findViewById(R.id.historicoAtendimento);
        btnHistoricoAtendimento.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnGraficosDeUso        = (Botton) findViewById(R.id.graficoDeUso);
        btnGraficosDeUso.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnExtratoDeAutenticacao= (Botton) findViewById(R.id.ExtratoAutenticacao);
        btnExtratoDeAutenticacao.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A visibilidade de uma *view* pode ter três estados:

- **visible** - a view é visível na tela.
- **invisible** - a view não é visível mas ocupa espaço.
- **gone** - a view não é visível e não ocupa espaço.

A visibilidade é controlada, no xml, pelo atributo [android:visibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility) e no java através do método [setVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)).

Para o que pretende deve usar o estado **gone**

java:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

xml:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @Ramaral, não tinha essa informação de que invisible ainda ocupava o espaço.

Answer (score 3):

Dentro da classe da `Activity`, utilize o objeto contendo este botão e quando entrar na condição para ficar invisível implemente:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Caso tenha alguma condição para retornar a visibilidade, utilize:

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: mas como faço para o espaço que o botão ocupava para não ficarm em branco? para que outro botão suba para o lugar dele.

Comment: Com `View.GONE` o layout se reorganiza, isso que está dizendo ocorre se vc usar `View.INVISIBLE`

Comment: Deu certo, Obrigado.

Comment: Por nada! Estamos aí...